# Something Wrong With Python Zip Cracker Script

Tags: python, zip

Well i followed a tutorial for this script, and when i run it... nothing happens... i click run module, and it just skips a line and waits for next input?? nothign actually happens (ie the password of my test file show up)

```
heres my script:
import zipfile

zFile = zipfile.ZipFile('lol.zip')
passFile = open('dictionary.txt')

for line in passFile.readlines():
    password = x.strip()
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print('[+] Password = ' + password)
        exit(0)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be referencing a variable that isn't defined

```
password = x.strip()
```

There's no x var in your code. You probably want line as your var.

Which is why your try except statement doesn't trigger the print command.

Comment: i changed the x to line... still not printing

Comment: it extracts the file .... just doesnt have anything in the folder that i put in it (.txt document) nor does it actually say the password

Comment: You're trying to write to the dictionary.txt? 

You might want to look at the zipfile documentation
https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects

From the documentation it looks like if you want to write all of the zipped contents to the .txt then you want

    zFile.extractall(passFile)

Comment: Is your dictionary.txt an empty file?

Comment: my .txt dictionary file has a bunch of possible combinations.. and no its far from empty..  got about couple hundred or thousand combinations.. basically i want the script to tell the password of the file using the combinations in the dictionary file

Answer (score 0):

An empty folder means that the password isn't working properly and the file is not extracting. I had this writing my script - when you make an incorrect password attempt, an empty archive folder will appear on your target path (i.e. on desktop). 
However if the password is correct then you see the contents properly. So empty folder means not opened properly, which probably means bad password.

<s>[Docs on strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) would suggest that you need to specify what you are stripping. If you are stripping whitespace try adding \n as a strip() parameter, so strip(\n). I think that you are pulling the right password, only it includes whitespace, so your password is invalid.</s>

**EDIT - you don't need to specify to remove whitespace.**

**"If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed."**

[docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

First things first:

1. [From documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), when you open a file, it is good practice to use 'with' keyword with file objects. I would apply this to the word list and the archive file. This means they will be closed properly without you specifying "closed".

   ```
   with open("words.txt", "r") as the_text:
   ```
2. What is x ? You haven't declared it anywhere. To go through your list, strip the lines and create a password you want something like this:

   ```
   with open("words.txt", "r") as the_text:
       for entry in the_text.readlines():
       password = entry.strip('\n')
   ```

This goes through every line in the text, strips out the whitespace (\n) and uses the resulting word as a password.

3. Then you need to pass that password to your .zip file. I would use try/except to raise a custom error (in this case no error message) and just keep trying until something comes up.

   ```
   try:
       with zipfile.ZipFile('arch.zip', 'r') as zf:
           zf.extractall(pwd=password)
           print '[+] Found password = ' + password + '\n'
           exit(0)
   except:
       pass
   ```

Again, here I use 'with' to open the zip file and use the variable zf
If the password matches and the file opens, it prints out the successful password and exits. Without the exit(0) it will keep trying to match passwords even if it finds the right one.

Something else to bear in mind is that Python is rubbish for this. It's effective but SLOW. Lots of answers on Stack for other recommendations, by people far more knowledgeable than I.

I am currently learning Python 2.7 and hope this is helpful. My finished script (tested and working with word list of 476k English words)

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as the_text:
    for entry in the_text.readlines():
        password = entry.strip('\n')
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile('arch.zip', 'r') as zf:
                zf.extractall(pwd=password)
                print '[+] Found password = ' + password + '\n'
                exit(0) 
        except:
        pass
```

Comment: Debugging is way easier when you start small. Try just opening the zip file with the password - with zipfile.ZipFile('arch.zip', 'r') as zf:  zf.extractall(pwd=password) 
Get this working first. Then try printing out words from the word file. Then put the two together. Otherwise it's much harder to find the problem.